# Laravel 5.5 custom exception handling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm using `Laravel 5.5` and am new to it. As concerns error handling, I found that Laravel has many facades and features built-in, however, I seem not to have wrapped my head around all the features it provides (to originally make my life easier).

What I want is that whenever an error occurs (i.e. exception's thrown), Laravel shall redirect the user to the previous page and display an error message (not the error itself, you don't want users to be able to see this in production; I thought of something like `'Error occurred'`).

I included a display for errors in all of my views, so I just need to pass (via POST I suppose) an array `message` with `title` and `message`, as well as `style` (using Bootstrap styles, e.g. `danger`, `warning`, `success`). Ideally, the exception is logged somewhere so I'm able to reproduce errors later on.

My current solution is devoid of Laravel's nice features since I just `try-catch` everywhere and redirect to a specific page (I've chosen to be 'the right one' for this error). Also, this oppresses the original error.

What is the best approach for my desire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Laravel's exception handler: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#the-exception-handler

You can achieve what you want by implementing custom `render()` method that would return a redirect response.

> The `render` method is responsible for converting a given exception into an HTTP response that should be sent back to the browser.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at this.

Comment: I already implemented this in my application when I noticed that now even validation errors are "oppressed" or overridden by my error message. I want everything except for this since I think the validation does a great job.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution which excludes the validation and thus supports Laravel's built-in validation error, whereas every other error is differently displayed:

```
Log::error($exception->getMessage());
if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException)
   return parent::render($request, $exception);

return redirect(URL::previous())->withErrors(['Error', 'Unknown Error']);
```

Thanks to @jedrzej.kurylo who posted a solution on where to start. The code above shall be used under `/App/Exceptions/Handler.php`, function `render`.